# Construct matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B$ any square matrix. Is possible to construct an invertible matrix $Q_B$ such that
$$\|Q_BBQ_B^{-1}\|_2\ \leq\ \rho(B)?$$

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Edit:** $Q_B$ only need to be invertible, not orthogonal.

Comment: Maybe, you can use the fact that, there's $U$ unitary, such that $U^*BU$ is an upper triangular matrix (Shur form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\rho(B)=\rho(Q_BBQ_B^{-1})$, you are essentially asking whether $B$ is similar to some $A$ such that $\|A\|_2=\rho(A)$, Yet, $\|A\|_2=\rho(A)$ if and only if $A$ is the scalar multiple of a unitary matrix. So, if $B$ is not similar to the scalar multiple of a unitary matrix (e.g. when $B$ has at least two eigenvalues of different moduli, or when $B$ is not normal), the construction of $Q_B$ is impossible.

Comment: I see, but then how do I can construct a $Q_B$, in the case of it's possible?

Comment: @ShanaKugimiya Unitary matrices are diagonalisable. So you may simply diagonalise $B$ and the resulting matrix will be a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries having identical moduli.